# duplicate sourcemaps with Angular Cli - webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

in the chrome developer tools I see multiple sourcemap to the same typescript file with GET. how can it be ? and what can I do to stay with only one ?

I'm using CLI-Webpack.

example for duplicate sourcemaps:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to promote the import of the module that holds this directive to app.module and it will solve this issue.